# Determine if Arduino is rapidly pulsed on and off several times

Tags: power

Greetings fellow humans!

I've set myself the task of ascertaining whether an Arduino has been rapidly power cycled to force it into a setup state, a feature common with many IoT devices. So I essentially need to keep a count - of, say, three - prior on/off cycles. I could look at a custom bootloader that stores a power-on count in EEPROM then check if the attempts are >= 3 once the sketch is running (resetting the count), but I'm concerned that the EEPROM data could become corrupted during the cycle, or the the power cycle would be so rapid for even a bootloader to complete the count at all.

So, I figure I need another solution: an external counter, powered by the Arduino, that increments each time the Arduino receives power, but doesn't rely on the Arduino getting so far as running anything of consequence to keep count.

Could some kind soul point me in the direction of a discrete counter solution that would fit the task?  The simpler (fewer discrete components) the better.

Thanks!

SOLVED: less-than-discrete but fully functional solution adopted; noted in comments. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: `Greetings fellow humans!` -- How dare you! I am not human!

Comment: Hello, Voldemort, good to see, that you are also an enthusiast of muggle technology XD

Comment: delete the bootloader and count the resets as first in sketch. on some MCUs a reset doesn't erase SRAM so a not initialized variable could hold the count. some MCUs have RTC memory, which is not cleared at reset.

Comment: @Juraj: Keeping the count in SRAM (in the .noinit section) would only work for warm resets. The OP seems to be concerned with power cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I settled on a reasonably trivial additive resistance PWM signal fed by a decade counter. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't.

How I would implement it is:

1. Have the MCU monitor the incoming power
2. Provide a large-ish reservoir of power (capacitor) to run the MCU for a short time
3. Isolate the incoming power monitoring from the reservoir with a diode

When the power is removed the MCU runs off the stored power in the capacitor. The MCU then sees that the power is removed (by 1 above) and maybe reduces its power by turning off as much as it can to prolong the runtime. If the power is re-applied before the reservoir runs out then it enters the setup state.  If the reservoir runs out, then not much really happens.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGNbb8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The size of the capacitor will determine the runtime. You may also choose to replace the capacitor with an "LC PI" filter to give more runtime but at the cost of space:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSWFNg.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I use a similar technique to buy enough time on power loss to ensure a graceful shutdown where necessary. However...  I dug out a bunch of 74LS90s and, through additive serial resistance, came up with a solution that near enough fits the criteria.